# Sorting 5th column in descending order error message

Tags: perl, sorting, ubuntu

The text file I am trying to sort:

```
MYNETAPP01-NY
700000123456
Filesystem               total       used      avail capacity  Mounted on
/vol/vfiler_PROD1_SF_NFS15K01/     1638GB      735GB      903GB      45%  /vol/vfiler_PROD1_SF_NFS15K01/
/vol/vfiler_PROD1_SF_NFS15K01/.snapshot      409GB      105GB      303GB      26%  /vol/vfiler_PROD1_SF_NFS15K01/.snapshot
/vol/vfiler_PROD1_SF_isci_15K01/     2048GB     1653GB      394GB      81%  /vol/vfiler_PROD1_SF_isci_15K01/
snap reserve               0TB        0TB        0TB     ---%  /vol/vfiler_PROD1_SF_isci_15K01/..
```

I am trying to sort this text file by its 5th column (the `capacity` field) in descending order.

When I first started this there was a percentage symbol mixed with the numbers. I solved this by substituting the the value like so: `s/%/ %/g for @data;`. This made it easier to sort the numbers alone. Afterwards I will change it back to the way it was with `s/ %/%/g`.

After running the script, I received this error:

> @ACI-CM-L-53:~$ ./netapp.pl
>   Can't use string ("/vol/vfiler_PROD1_SF_isci_15K01/"...) as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at ./netapp.pl line 20,  line 24 (#1)

> ```
>    (F) You've told Perl to dereference a string, something which  
>    use strict blocks to prevent it happening accidentally.  See  
>    "Symbolic references" in perlref.  This can be triggered by an @ or $  
>    in a double-quoted string immediately before interpolating a variable,  
>    for example in "user @$twitter_id", which says to treat the contents  
>    of $twitter_id as an array reference; use a \ to have a literal @  
>    symbol followed by the contents of $twitter_id: "user \@$twitter_id".
> ```

```
Uncaught exception from user code:  
        Can't use string ("/vol/vfiler_PROD1_SF_isci_15K01/"...) as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at ./netapp.pl line 20, <$DATA> line 24.
```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

open (my $DATA, "<raw_info.txt") or die "$!";

my $systemName = <$DATA>;
my $systemSN   = <$DATA>;
my $header     = <$DATA>;

my @data;
while ( <$DATA> ) {
    @data = (<$DATA>);
}

s/%/ %/g   for @data;
s/---/000/ for @data;

print @data;

my @sorted = sort { $b->[5] <=> $a->[5] } @data;
print @sorted;

close($DATA);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, let me try that out and I will update.
Edit: Tried this, and it pushed the data into the array properly; however, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Is your input a fixed file? I mean: it's presumably the output of some `df` command. There are ways (i.e. command line parameters to `df`) to format that output to make sorting easier. Is that possible in your case?

Comment: The columns are fixed, but the data could be different. Basically, this is one generated instance of the system, but the script should be able to sort any generated reports of similar format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach using [Text::Table](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Table) which will nicely align your output into neat columns.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Table;

open my $DATA, '<', 'file1' or die $!;

<$DATA> for 1 .. 2; # throw away first two lines
chomp(my $hdr = <$DATA>); # header

my $tbl = Text::Table->new( split ' ', $hdr, 6 );

$tbl->load( map [split /\s{2,}/], sort by_percent <$DATA> );
print $tbl;

sub by_percent {
    my $keya = $a =~ /(\d+)%/ ? $1 : '0';
    my $keyb = $b =~ /(\d+)%/ ? $1 : '0';
    $keyb <=> $keya
}
```

The output generated is:

```
Filesystem                              total  used   avail capacity Mounted on                             
/vol/vfiler_PROD1_SF_isci_15K01/        2048GB 1653GB 394GB 81%      /vol/vfiler_PROD1_SF_isci_15K01/       
/vol/vfiler_PROD1_SF_NFS15K01/          1638GB 735GB  903GB 45%      /vol/vfiler_PROD1_SF_NFS15K01/         
/vol/vfiler_PROD1_SF_NFS15K01/.snapshot 409GB  105GB  303GB 26%      /vol/vfiler_PROD1_SF_NFS15K01/.snapshot
snap reserve                            0TB    0TB    0TB   ---%     /vol/vfiler_PROD1_SF_isci_15K01/..
```

**Update**

To explain some of the *advanced* parts of the program.

```
my $tbl = Text::Table->new( split ' ', $hdr, 6 );
```

This creates the Text::Table object with the header split into 6 columns. Without the limit of 6 columns, it would have created 7 columns (because the last field, 'mounted on', also contains a space. It would have been incorrectly split into 2 columns for a total of 7).

```
$tbl->load( map [split /\s{2,}/], sort by_percent <$DATA> );
```

The statement above 'loads' the data into the table. The `map` applies a transformation to each line from `<$DATA>`. Each line is split into an anonymous array, (created by `[....]`). The split is on 2 or more spaces, `\s{2,}`. If that wasn't specified, then the data `snap reserve' with 1 space would have been incorrectly split.

I hope this makes whats going on more clear.

And a simpler example that doesn't align the columns like Text::Table, but leaves them in the form they originally were read might be:

```
open my $DATA, '<', 'file1' or die $!;

<$DATA> for 1 .. 2; # throw away first two lines
my $hdr = <$DATA>; # header

print $hdr;
print sort by_percent <$DATA>;

sub by_percent {
    my $keya = $a =~ /(\d+)%/ ? $1 : '0';
    my $keyb = $b =~ /(\d+)%/ ? $1 : '0';
    $keyb <=> $keya
}
```

Comment: Wow! I haven't gotten to tables yet on my tutorial, but will look into this. Thank you for your input! +1

Comment: @Andrew Nguyen I have added some explanation of how the code works. Hope it clears up some of the more difficult parts. Also provided a solution that doesn't use Text::Table.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to skipping the fourth line of the file, this line is wrong

```
my @sorted = sort { $b->[5] <=> $a->[5] } @data
```

But presumably you knew that as the error message says

> at ./netapp.pl line 20

`$a` and `$b` are lines of text from the array `@data`, but you're treating them as array references. It looks like you need to extract the fifth "field" from both variables before you compare them, but no one can tell you how to do that

Comment: Thanks for the response. When you say there's only one line of text in @data, did you mean the $data[0] hold all the data? I used Dumper to extract all the information, and it seems like it is in different indexes.

Comment: @Andrew: I'm sorry, I was wrong. Your program reads three lines into three scalar variables. Then `while ( <$DATA> )` reads a line and puts it into `$_` which you never use. If that line was *true* then `@data = (<$DATA>)` reads all of the rest of the file into `@data`. The next iteration of the `while` loop is at end of file so it exits and continues with your substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

You code is quite far from what you want. Trying to change it as little as possible, this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $fh, "<", "raw_info.txt") or die "$!";

my $systemName = <$fh>;
my $systemSN = <$fh>;
my $header = <$fh>;

my @data;
while( my $d = <$fh> ) {
  chomp $d;
  my @fields = split '\s{2,}', $d;
  if( scalar @fields > 4 ) {
    $fields[4] = $fields[4] =~ /(\d+)/ ? $1 : 0;
    push @data, [ @fields ];
  }
}

foreach my $i ( @data ) {
  print join("\t", @$i), "\n";
}

my @sorted = sort { $b->[4] <=> $a->[4] } @data;

foreach my $i ( @sorted ) {
  $i->[4] .= '%';
  print join("\t", @$i), "\n";
}

close($fh);
```

Let´s make a few things clear:

1. If using the `$` notation, it is customary to define file variables in lower case as `$fd`. It is also typical to name the *file descriptor* as "fd".
2. You define but not use the first three variables. If you don´t apply `chomp` to them, the final CR will be added to them. I have not done it as they are not used.
3. You are defining a list with a line in each element. But then you need a list ref inside to separate the fields.
4. The separation is done using `split`.
5. Empty lines are skipped by counting the number of fields.
6. I use something more compact to get rid of the `%` and transform the `---` into a `0`.
7. Lines are added to list `@data` using `push` and turning the list to add into a list ref with `[ @list ]`.
8. A list of list refs needs two loops to get printed. One traverses the list (`foreach`), another (implicit in `join`) the columns.
9. Now you can sort the list and print it out in the same way. By the way, Perl lists (or arrays) start at index 0, so the 5th column is 4.

This is not the way I would have coded it, but I hope it is clear to you as it is close to your original code.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look over what you sent and study it to better understand PERL. EDIT: While the code provided did not sort, it is more than enough information for me to get this working. Marking as solved! Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Also, check other people´s comments. Some of them make a lot of sense. You probably need to review some kind of Perl introduction to understand all of this. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, this was for a Linux class I'm taking. Before Thanksgiving break, we only had one solid lecture session to prepare us for this assignment. I am studying on my own through guides, but was just stuck on that error.

Comment: If you don´t have a book, you may want to start with this introduction, [perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html).